# How to networking with PC's no matter what OS they use

Tags: c#, networking

I have a little bit stupid Question!!
I'm writing a little application with C# and the Network programming work with Windows PC's.

I watch some newbies Tutorials from Microsoft that's why.

So now i just want to know, how i can program so that my application can connect to all PC's or Mac not regarding the OS(Win, Linux, Mac OS).

It's possible? when yes how?

Thanks a lot for Helping!

Comment: Take a look at the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mono to develop in C# and deploy your application to Windows / Linux and Mac OS.

You can use a web service, and your client application on other OS's can all connect to a webservice and use it, even if you end up developing your clients in another cross OS language like java.

On the other hand you could use tcp/ip, or udp protocols depending on your application needs.

It really depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your application running on different PCs and then they talk to each other then yes, have a look at Mono. Basically it means you can write your program in .NET and then run it everywhere where an implementation of the .NET platform is available (Mono supports Windows, Linux and Mac OS).

Otherwise you need to specify as to what your application wants to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

They solved this problem and the solution was web services.
If you want TCP/IP that's another story.